# Restrict aws security groups on kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, aws-security-group

I created my kubernetes cluster with specified security group for each ec2 server type, for example for backend server I have backend-sg associated with and a node-sg which is created with the cluster.

Now I try to restrict access to my backend ec2 and open only port 8090 as an inbound and port 8080 as an outbound to a specific security group (lets call it frontend-sg).

I was manage to do so but when changing the inbound port to 8081 in order to check that those restrictions actually worked I was still able to acess port 8080 from the frontend-sg ec2.

I think I am missing something...
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: do you have k8s api related ports open between groups? Are all of your nodes in node-sg regardless of function?

Comment: Yes, in the nodes-sg there are api related porrs open between all security groups in the cluster (Created in cluster creation). And yes all nodes are in nodes-sg

Answer (score 0):

> Any help would be appriciated

I will try to illustrate situation in this answer to make it more clear. If I'm understanding your case correctly, this is what you have so far:

[image: AWS Sec groups overview]

Now if you try ports from Frontend EC2 instance to Backend EC2 instance, and they are in same security group (node-sg) you will have traffic there. If you want to check group isolation then you should have one instance outside of node-sg and only in frontend-sg targetting any instance in backend-sg (supposing that both node-sg and backend-sg are not permitting said ports for inbound traffic)...

Finally, a small note... Kubernetes is by default closing all traffic (and you need ingress, loadbalancer, upstream proxy, nodePort or some other means to actually expose your front-facing services) so traditional fine graining of backend/frontend instances and security groups is not that "clearcut" when using k8s, especially since you don't really want to schedule manually (or by labels for that matter) which instances pods will actually run (but instead leave that to k8s scheduler for better unitilization of resources).